# Selection based on focused TopComponent's activated Node & comonent posion custamization

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am new to Netbeans RCP. I started with Quick start(http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-quick-start.html).

After finishing part 3 of tutorial I was unable to understand few points.
1. "History window" looses all data if I shift focus from "Text window" to "History window" (i,e on clicking "History window") - Why? and how can I prevent this?
2. If I make one more explorer component, say  "Second History window", explorer components will be grouped (as default explorer position) on application start. How can specify positions of components on start up?

Comment: You may have better luck asking this question in the NetBeans Platform Users forum. http://forums.netbeans.org/platform-users.html

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to how you process Lookup changes. When you shift focus an event is sent with an empty result. So make sure you check for that in your logic

```
@Override
    public void resultChanged(LookupEvent le) {
        Lookup.Result res = (Lookup.Result) le.getSource();
        Collection instances = res.allInstances();

        if (!instances.isEmpty()) {
            <update>
        }else{
            <do nothing>
        }
    }
```